# Polyandry in birds

Tags: zoology, ornithology, ethology, sexual-reproduction

The Wikipedia article on [Bateman's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bateman%27s_principle) states:

> Until recently, most bird species were believed to be sexually
> monogamous. DNA paternity testing, however, has shown that in nearly
> 90% of bird species, females copulate with multiple males during each
> breeding season

citing two articles. But the [Polyandry in nature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry_in_nature) article says:

> Polyandry… occurs in … around 1% of all bird species, such as jacanas
> and dunnocks.

(No cites provided.)

Am I correct that the second article should be updated?

Comment: "no citation provided" would be the relevant information.

Comment: I did work on the Louisiana waterthrush 15 years ago and found some instances of polyandry. Wasn't previously recorded in that species to my knowledge

Answer (score -1):

I think you're confused about the definition of polyandry. Firstly, polyandry normally refers to sustained relationships, not simply mating. In birds this means nest biulding, incubating eggs, and feeding young. If a pair of birds raise chicks in one nest, and neither interacts with another nest of chicks, then they are a monogamous pair - it doesn't matter if there are other chicks with their genetic material.

Also, polyandry normally refers to females taking more than one male partner, while males stick with that single female. The article states that most females "cheat" on their partners but a similar percentage of males do the same.

The dunnocks given as an example often form trios where 2 males and a female collectively raise chicks, with the young having a mixture of paternities. The jacanas have a system where males build nests and females claim up to 4 males, and defends all her nests while the males raise the young. These are very different to the standard bird system, where a female bird may have many sexual partners, but only cares for one set of young.

Comment: Do you have a cite for “polyandry normally refers to sustained relationships, not simply mating”? Both https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Animal_Behavior/Polyandry#Polyandry and 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyandry_in_nature start w defn in terms only of mating. Perhaps in parallel with ‘social monogamy’, (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_monogamy_in_mammalian_species#Monogamy_in_mammals), 
nest building, etc., could be termed ‘social polyandry’?

Comment: It also varies among species. A study by the local college ( Sam Houston , Huntsville TX) found Carolina Wrens were almost monogamous; different from other birds studied . It was years ago and I do not recall what species were in the study.